# Cannot commit jar file to svn after merge: 502 'Bad Gateway'

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn, visualsvn

We use visualsvn with tortoiseSVN on the client for version control of the binaries. That is, when we want to test a project, the test branch is merged with the build branch. This essentially updates the jar file to a newer version.

For some reason i cannot commit the now merged test branch, i get a 502 'Bad Gateway' error. **I can commit some of the updated files**, i have comitted the delete of the old jar file but i cannot commit the new jar.

The error i get **points to the build** branch, not the test branch, which i think may be the cause. I have tried deleting the offending file and replacing it with a copy from the build (sort of manual merge). But i get the same error.

```
Commit failed (details follow):
Unexpected HTTP status 502 'Bad Gateway' on
'/svn/binaries/!svn/rvr/11730/myProject/branches/build/newestversion.jar'
```

**EDIT:** The error has something to do with the merge. After undoing the *add*, i have copied the jar file into the test directory, added it and commited without any hick-ups.

The error propagates: after merging staging with test, i get the same error as above but with:

'/svn/binaries/!svn/rvr/11737/myProject/branches/**tst**/newestversion.jar'

Comment: a n t i v i r u s or p r o x y

Comment: I would not be able to commit the jar that was just added and not merged if it was antivirus or proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per investigation with support@visualsvn.com, the root cause was the following line in the `%VISUALSVN_SERVER%conf\httpd-custom.conf` file:

```
RequestHeader edit Destination ^https http early
```

Removing this line resolves the issue.

BTW, I can guess that the line was added to implement automatic redirection from HTTP to HTTPS. With modern VisualSVN Server versions, you can enable this redirection via the VisualSVN Server Manager console. Therefore, no need to add that line to the conf file.

You can follow these steps:

1. Start the **VisualSVN Server Manager** console.
2. Click **Action | Properties**.
3. Click **Network** tab.
4. Select the **Automatically redirect HTTP to HTTPS (listen on port 80)** option.
5. Click **Apply**.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP status code 502 is a server side error:

[RFC 7231 section 6.6.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.3):

> The 502 (Bad Gateway) status code indicates that the server, while
> acting as a gateway or proxy, received an invalid response from an
> inbound server it accessed while attempting to fulfill the request.

As you are checking in binary files it could be a timeout from a server between you and the svn servern as the checking takes too long. So you should check the svn server and any server between you and the svn server.

Comment: As it may have been the size of the .jar, i tried commiting a considerably larger test-file (30 mb versus 20 mb), but that went fine.

Comment: After removing the file, and undoing the add (removing it from version control) i commited a copy of the same file without any problems. Somehow the merge causes this problem.

Comment: Can you see something in the server log?

Comment: Unfortunately no. We have VisualSVN on windows and the event viewer tells me nothing. I can confirm the issue only happens when i try to commit a merge with a new file, and it happens every time with a new file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using **RouixSVN** and I only had to **clear** the SVN **authentication** data on my computer and log in again and it worked. Hope it helps someone else.

On an Ubuntu system this is done by deleting:

```
~/.subversion/auth
```

on Windows:

```
%APPDATA%\Subversion\auth
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue.  The problem I saw is the branch called for a SVN COPY to happen and this is done in HTTP and breaks under HTTPS.  So I created a localhost:9005 virtual host running DAV, added the localhost:9005 listner, and changed my SSL virtual host to proxy to the localhost:9005.

...
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/server.cer
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/server.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/domain.cer

```
ProxyRequests           On
ProxyPreserveHost       On

ProxyPass           /svn    http://localhost:9005/svn
ProxyPassReverse    /svn    http://localhost:9005/svn
```