# What exactly happens during merge and branching?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

What exactly goes on between client (Tortoise SVN) and server (Visual SVN)  during merge and branching, and how is is different from checkout and commit?

When I try to branch or merge using Tortoise SVN, I get a `502 'Bad Gateway` error, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49942606/cannot-commit-jar-file-to-svn-after-merge-502-bad-gateway).

I do not get this error when I check out or commit. So my guess is that more communication goes back and forth when i do a merge or branch, as compared to checkout or commit.

The network (and technically the server too, but not Visual SVN itself) is maintained by another company and i would like to be able to explain to them i'm doing, precisely,  when i get an error.

We also have IIS running on the same machine as Visual SVN, not sure if it's relevant.

Comment: Before you have proof that it is related to IIS, please avoid using that tag. Visual SVN is not an open source product, so for such issues, your best resource is their support page https://www.visualsvn.com/support/

Comment: @Lex, I understand. I dont think it's related to ISS per se, but i do think we may have some non-default settings to make it possible to run both ISS and VisualSVN on the same machine.

Comment: @LexLi I regularly monitor and answer `svn` and VisualSVN -related questions here, BTW.

Answer (score 0):

Try reproducing this issue directly on the server computer. I.e. run the **svn.exe** client on the server computer and use the localhost URL. If the problem does not reproduce, investigate how your server is configured.

Do you use IIS as a reverse proxy? If you do, this behavior indicates that IIS is configured incorrectly (check the rewrite rules as in this thread [Can't commit several files from Visual Studio project to subversion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46254149/761095)).

Please also note that DAV protocol implementation used in Subversion relies on server root-relative URLs. It means that proxied/rewritten URI must be identical to the original one.

And don't forget to make sure that you use a supported VisualSVN Server and SVN version. Upgrade to VisualSVN Server 3.9.x and TortoiseSVN 1.10.x - there is no practical reason to use older versions, IMHO.

Comment: What svn steps do i need to do to reproduce branching? Running svn command-line (svn help) gives me a list of opotions, but does not include 'branch'.

Comment: `svn copy https://URL https://URL -m TEST` http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.copy.html